# How to install a insulation meter in panel

Tags: electrical, insulation, installation, meter

I want to install a fix insulation meter in a main switch board . There is lot of motors in the switch board . If there is a requirement of taking insulation we check all the motors one by one. Plz some one provide connection diagram of installation of the insulation meter.

Comment: maybe install an interlock and connect the insulation tester as you would a generator, the tester isn't going to power the control electronics for the motors so that may not work well.

Comment: You probably don't want to subject non-motory-things to hi-pot test voltages (lots of electronics have MOVs in the power-supply front end to catch unwanted surges, and a hi-pot test will kill those MOVs dead short and thus force an unexpected service call on w/e gizmo got hit)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about home improvement. It appears to be a commercial project.

Comment: You would be better served by monitoring the ground voltage/current this is not usually done until the service is over 800 amps and that would not be a home diy. If your home has a bunch of fans to control an indoor garden or “Grow” as they are called in my area it could be a DIY but more information would be needed.